# Is it possible to implement seamless update in a ROM for nexus 5?

Tags: custom-roms, nexus-5, 7.0-nougat

[Android Nougat’s “Seamless Updates”, Explained](https://www.howtogeek.com/269595/android-nougats-seamless-updates-explained/)

Seamless update feeature that was implementated in Android Nougat needs proper hardware config to work, which is nothing but another partition created specifically so that future updates get installed in 2nd partition and next time phone reboots, 2nd partition is used as system partition.

will it be possible to do if I created 2nd partition myself?

are their any Custom ROM available for hammerhead or hammerheadcaf that has this feature?

Comment: This is not a simple feat if it is probably possible.  To start with you would have to host your own servers, generate your own keys for security and greatly modify it.  I do believe is definitely possible considering OEMs do this with there own custom ROMs like the Galaxy devices.

Comment: @William Xiomi Mi3 had this feature well before nougat (not as good though, damn these Google Pixel's update fast), to flash custom ROM on that we had to remove the second partition, by installing a new partition table. do you have the link or little bit more info on what you're suggesting

Comment: Why do you want this feature?

Comment: @William why do want anything at all? || (better answer) I'm just tinkering with my Nexus 5 now, as I've got a new phone, so that's it

Comment: You can flash newer Android versions without loosing your data so I can find this question not ideal.  I personal prefer manually updating instead receiving updates whenever.